# Weird error tryying to connect to remote pg db while using jdbc

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc

Im writing a simple java program that interacts with my remote Postgres database.
The important parts are these:

```
static final String url = "jdbc:postgresql://XX.XXX.XXX.XX:5432/DBNAME";
//...
public static void dbConnect() {
    try {
        dbConnection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
        System.out.println("Connected to the PostgreSQL server successfully.");
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Now the thing is that my remote server where the database exists got ip XX.XXX.XXX.XX.When i run the above program i got an error that says:

```
FATAL: no pg_hba.conf entry for host "YY.YYY.YY.YY", user "postgres", database "DBNAME", SSL off
```

The ip address i get on my error its pointing to my router's page same like 192.168.1.1(YY.YYY.YY.YY) .

My /etc/postgresql/9.5/main/pg_hba.conf looks like this(the important parts)

```
host     all             all             XX.XXX.XXX.XX/24   trust
```

My /etc/postgresql/9.5/main/postgesql.conf looks like this(the important parts)

```
listen_addresses = '*'
port = 5432
```

Also the command

```
 psql -h XX.XXX.XXX.XX  -U postgres
```

in a bash console connects me succesfully to the DB.
Any clues?

EDIT:
With the exact same program i have succesfully connected and executed queries about half day ago.I didnt change any settings on the server/program and now its like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue is similar to https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/83984/connect-to-postgresql-server-fatal-no-pg-hba-conf-entry-for-host

**Solution:**

Add to postgresql.conf:

```
listen_addresses = '*'
```

Add to pg_hba.conf:

```
host  all  all 0.0.0.0/0 md5
```